# Spring/Acegi security for REST Webservices in WebApplication?

Tags: security, spring, rest

Our current app is a standard spring 2.5 application with Form Based Authentication using Acegi. However, we need to expose some REST Service for 3rd party application and we are trying to use BASIC auth over SSL. We have used RESTEAsy for exposing the REST Services. Now, given that the rest of the application uses form & Session based authentication, how can I enable basic authentication for the few REST Services.

To me, the usecase seems normal, however, I couldn't find much reference on the web. Any comment/suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can use OAuth. Spring already provide API to implement that http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/userguide.html

Comment: OAuth is too complex for my needs. I just need basic auth over SSL.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the more general question of whether to secure the REST service using **Form authentication** or **Basic/Digest authentication** - this is deeply tied into one of the more important constraints of RESTful architecture - **statelessness**.

With this in mind, logging into a service means keeping state on the server, which goes against the stateless server constraint. From an authentication POV, Form based authentication implies logging in, whereas Basic/Digest authentication means **embedding the authentication credentials in each request**, with no need to keep any state on the server. This is why this kind of authentication is much more inline with the way REST is meant to be build.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You've almost got a +1 from me, but could you say anything about using Form auth instead of Digest in that pair so that the question is answered? (If it's just a matter of switching things around and it otherwise Just Works — as I suspect it might be — then saying that clearly would be tremendously valuable and earn that upvote.)

Comment: Edited the original response, adding some details. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Basic/Digest Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#basic) in the Spring Security Reference.

Comment: Well, as I said, I am already using form based authentication so there is already an authentication entry point. My question was if its possible to have Basic & Form Based authentication co exist together in the same security configuration file.

Comment: Yes it is.   You will need to add the filter to your config.

Comment: I am trying to do that without much luck, may be doing some silly mistake. Can you point me to some sample / reference code? Thanks.